# SharePoint search index drive space estimation for full crawl

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I am supporting SharePoint 2013 live environment with 15 Million items in search index.

I have large site with 150 GB data and this site needs full crawl.

But my search server index drive is only left with 200 GB free space.

Since disk size would be maximum utilized during full crawl, will this 200 Gb index drive sufficient for running full crawl of 150 GB site?

Comment: No easy way to answer that question. It depends on your data. If the data will be similar to the rest of the farm work it out based on your existing index...

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use 20-30 percent of the crawled content as an estimate. So in your case you need about 4.5 GB for the index (depending on what kind of content you are indexing). The reality is you'll need less in actual storage, only 10-12 percent, but before the merge the disk can grow to that 20-30% number.

In you case I'd be more concerned that you are over the 10 Million Items per index partition limit. You need two index partitions for 15 million items.